# Css background-color: none;

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, sass

**How i can use green color**

[image: background-color]
how i can disabled ".ladda-button[disabled]:hover" button color as this class add in jQuery after page load

.ladda-button[disabled], .ladda-button[disabled]:hover, .ladda-button[data-loading], .ladda-button[data-loading]:hover {
    background-color: none;
}

```
.ladda-button[disabled], 
.ladda-button[disabled]:hover, 
.ladda-button[data-loading], 
.ladda-button[data-loading]:hover {
    cursor: default;
    background-color: #111;
 }

.btn-success.disabled, .btn-success:disabled {
    background-color: #00644a;
    border-color: #00644a;
}

.ladda-button[disabled], 
.ladda-button[disabled]:hover, 
.ladda-button[data-loading], 
.ladda-button[data-loading]:hover {
    background-color: none;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried adding !important ?

Comment: how i can disabled ".ladda-button[disabled]:hover" button color as this class add in jQuery after page load

Comment: You can't disable it if it is generated from cdn or so... So put important in your css code so it replaces the jquery's cdn content

Comment: Can you please post your html to your question so we can provide a fix. Instead of !important I recommend using css specificity instead - the more specific the selector, the more precise it can be; within reason.

Answer (score 2):

Add following lines to your css

```
.ladda-button[disabled] .ladda-button[disabled]:hover {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 255, 0) !important
}
```

here, give background color which you want. I have given transparent.

Comment: FYI, it's spelled "transparent", in case you used rgba() simply because you didn't know how to spell it correctly (which is fair, it's not the easiest word to spell). Still there really is no reason to use !important.

Comment: using important overrides default css. In my case, I always prefer to use important to override default css. I spelled it wrongly and it was typing mistake. I have edited it now.

Comment: @BoltClock : everyone here is not a native English speaker.

Comment: @Nitin Dhomse: That's why I noted that "it's not the easiest word to spell".

Comment: @Samiksha Jagtap: Well in that case I'm puzzled as to why you're not using "transparent" in your CSS. It's very unusual for anyone to go out of their way *not* to use it and to use rgba() instead. And no, you don't need !important to override "default css", whatever that means.